# Storing a large JSON string in DB table, as a mean to cache as API request. Good idea?

Tags: json, postgresql, caching, asp.net-web-api

Is there anything wrong with this idea?

I have 3 JSON API endpoints that rarely change data. Yet, every time someone opens my app... they are queried. There's about 20000 rows among the 3 endpoints.

What I want to do, is rather than access my postgresql DB every time for the data, which is very costly... I want to take the rendered JSON and put it into a new table called "cached_data" for example. I will take the JSON string which might have 10000 entries for example, and store it in a text column type in the "cached_data" table. for say 60 minutes.

Then when the endpoint is accessed... it will look at cached_data first. If it has been less than 60 minutes, the JSON string in cached_data will be returned. If it's been greater than 60 minutes, then we'll go to the database for the data.

Is this an acceptable idea/optimization? Can anyone see any issues with storing this large JSON string in a DB column?

Comment: Have you considered memcached or Varnish? It sounds like that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Agree with @SimeonVisser, there is no point maintaining another table with "cache". You can take a look at smth like memcached, redis.

Comment: @Dmitry smth? What is that.

Comment: @SimeonVisser how exactly does it work? Is there a ruby gem for it, or what is it?

Comment: Apologies, smth = something . As for memcached or redis configuration you can check their official documentation to begin with. Memcached is a little bit easier to configure , in general they ( redis or memcached ) can be used as in memory store, which is obviously faster than reading from disk ( database). Sorry for typos as I'm writing from the phone

Comment: A memory cache would be faster to retrieve, but consider also whether you need persistence. If so then storing the data in postgresql would not be a bad choice.